# Exporting Animated/Time series maps

Tags: timemanager, animatedmarker

I want to create a animate map using the TimeManager plugin in QGIS and then be able to upload it as an assignment at school.

Once it is created, how can I save the animated map as a video?

Answer (score 3):

Referencing the **[documentation page](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/time%20manager/)**, Anita Graser, aka @underdark writes:

> To export the animation, click the Export video button. If you are
>   using Linux, you can export videos directly from QGIS. On Windows, you
>   first need to export the animation frames as individual pictures,
>   which you can then convert to a video (for example using the free
>   Windows Movie Maker application).

She also mentions this on [**this page**](https://anitagraser.com/2011/11/20/nice-animations-with-time-managers-offset-feature/).

> Time Manager also enables you to export the animation to an image
>   series using “Export Video” button. Actual video export is not
>   implemented yet, but you can use mencoder (Windows users can download
>   it from Gianluigi Tiesi’s site) on the resulting image series to
>   create a video file:

```
mencoder "mf://*.PNG" -mf fps=10 -o output.avi -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4
```

Comment: Hi Fezter, thanks so much for the reply. I also wanted to know how to do it for Macs? Is it the same as for Linux - directly export?

Comment: I would imagine so.